# Repairing/reinstalling kali linux rolling

Tags: macbook-pro, kali-linux

Am using "kali linux rolling" on an macbook. I did the "purge" command & curiosity took hold of me, ended up putting "*" for everything. It was too late when I realised that even my system files were being purged. Restarted my laptop & I now can't login. How do I repair this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Grab your usb and start from scratch. Its the only way :/

Refer to official kali documentation for installation instructions:

[Current](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install)

Answer (score 0):

Hey if I got to you before reinstall and there are files that you wish to keep then check out my answer for recovering deleted files on [bitcoin.stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/49499/18794) for some steps you can try for recovering deleted files. Note it ain't going to help in recovery of the OS nearly as much as recovery of personal files.

Also it maybe possible to USB boot the device and mount the internal drive for recovering non-deleted files too. But know that regardless of recovery that Tealkine is correct in that reinstall will be the swiftest way of getting Kali Rolling up again.

Comment: Thus, have got to unscrew the laptop and format the drive on another machine? Or is there any way of reinstalling without necessarily unscrewing it?  By the way, most of the files in the laptop are those i can do without...   Thanks your responses guys

Comment: Most devices have the option to boot OSs from USB (or lucky Android users ROMs from SD) for the linked to recovery options. Mac maybe different or difficult to boot from external media but shouldn't be impossible but it has been awhile since I've had to hack'round in a Mac device. In short unscrewing should not be required to preform recovery or modding of the target drive. If you can do without the personal files then definitely re-install to save yourself time & headache. The above is of you have something worth saving or want to chroot to the fs & reinstall purged packages.

Comment: Just in case your search engine is broken; here's the [USB boot Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key) Q&A thread that seems like a good place to start on making a bootable USB distro. Nothing overly complicated just seems *hit & miss* on if your Mac will recognize the USB drive during boot, however, if you've an optical drive then a "Live CD" for booting seems to be the most compatible way of booting off a non-internal storage device.